# defining output as unbound (1x:inf) vector for matlab coder

Tags: c++, c, matlab, struct, matlab-coder

I'm having trouble defining a vector to be unbound when i use the Coder to generate C code. I wish to have a vector of type double 1x:inf, that will later generate a pointer to a struct containing the unbound vector when using Coder.

```
function [V2SAgent,bMove,s_Result] = V2SOnPublishedPrice(V2SAgent, oPPdata, ePochNow)
    %#codegen
    bMove = false;

      s_Result = struct('d_BidMove', zeros(1,0),'d_AskMove', zeros(1,0),'i_VolBands', zeros(1,0));
      coder.varsize('s_Result(:).d_BidMove',[1,inf],[false,true]));
      coder.varsize('s_Result(:).d_AskMove',[1,inf],[false,true]));
      coder.varsize('s_Result(:).i_VolBands',[1,inf],[false,true]));
      coder.cstructname(s_Result, 'Move_t');
      .....DOES ALOT OF WORK .....
```

When i process the function with the coder i end up with a struct looking like this.

```
struct emxArray_real_T_1x0
{
  int size[2];
};

typedef struct {
    emxArray_real_T_1x0 d_BidMove;
    emxArray_real_T_1x0 d_AskMove;
    emxArray_real_T_1x0 i_VolBands;
  } Move_T;
```

The type emxArray_real_T_1x0 is by no means unbound. In other scenarios I managed to achieve the output I'm looking for using the Input, that I can define to be of time 1x:inf using the Coder, and using this to set the output variable in my function.

```
function s_Result = V2SOnPublishedPrice(infVector)
    %#codegen

        s_Result = struct('d_BidMove', zeros(1,0))
        coder.varsize('s_Result(:).d_BidMove');
        coder.varsize(d_BidMove);
        coder.cstructname(s_Result, 'Move_t');
        ....SOME WORK....
        s_Result.d_BidMove = infVector;
  end
```

When put though to coder where infVector is defined as 1x:inf i get a output like this.

```
struct emxArray_real_T
{
  double *data;
  int *size;
  int allocatedSize;
  int numDimensions;
  boolean_T canFreeData;
};

typedef struct {
  emxArray_real_T *d_BidMove;
  emxArray_real_T *d_AskMove;
  emxArray_real_T *i_VolBands;
} Move_T;
```

For the scenario I used to define and test my functions this is fine, but I know I can't cover all the possible inputs I can get, so I need an output that is unbound so I have a uniform input/output across my functions, and I don't risk getting size mismatch or out of range errors.